# Как в Phalcon из Модели занести значения в сессию?

Tags: php, сессия, phalcon

Доброго времени суток, испытываю странные непонятки с этой птичкой...
Из контроллера в сессию я могу положить что угодно: `$this->session->set("variable", "value");`

А при попытке это выполнить в модели у меня ничего не выходит: делаю `$this->session->set("variable", "value");` Сервер выдает ошибку 500 и все... никакого пояснения... в Error.log так же ничего не заносится (

Подскажите, где я сплоховал?

Comment: Очевидно, в модели нет свойста session. Более того, модель не должна ничего заносить в сессию, потому что сессия существует исключительно в контетксте запроса, а модель - не только в нем.

Answer (score 5):

В модели нельзя обращаться к сессии на прямую так как он ее ищет в релейшинах или полях таблицы.
Для обращении к сессии необходимо использовать контейнер DI.
Пример:
`$this->geDI()->getSession()->set('name', 'value')`

Не рекомендовал бы назначать сессию в модели, если это не оправданно, так как можешь потом потеряться, модель предназначена для БД.